# Плагин emmet в vscode

Tags: html, emmet

emmet отказывается раскрывать теги, классы и вообще все что угодно в файле index.html. Если создам пустой файл .html, то там все гуд.
Не работает именно в файле проекта index.html.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

Спасибо.

Comment: попробуйте заглянуть сюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888869/visual-studio-code-emmet-not-working

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема было в том, что я скопировал иконки в svg-формате из репозитория, после этого плагин и перестал работать. Когда я вернул свои иконки, все заработало)